# How to get the city name by latitude and longitude using openstreetmap in android

Tags: android, osmdroid, openstreetmap

In my app i am using osm rather than google map.I have latitude and longitude.So from here how i will query to get the city name from osm database..plz help me.I am using osmdroid-android-3.0.8.is there any extra library i have to download for this?

Answer (score 15):

This can be done through [Reverse Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding), where you convert a Latitude/Longitude point into a human readable address. Typically, reverse geocoding is done as a web-request.

In your case, Open Street Maps has a [reverse geocoding API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding_.2F_Address_lookup) where you can make requests to their web service and then consume the xml/json response to get the city name.

Making reverse geocode request to the osm web service would look something like this:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=[LATITUDE]&lon=[LONGITUDE]&zoom=18&addressdetails=1
```

Where:

- [LATITUDE] is the latitude point to be reverse geocoded.
- [LONGITUDE] is the longitude point to be reverse geocoded.

This will give you a result that looks something like so:

```
<reversegeocode timestamp="Fri, 06 Nov 09 16:33:54 +0000" querystring="...">
   <result place_id="1620612" osm_type="node" osm_id="452010817">
     135, Pilkington Avenue, Wylde Green, City of Birmingham, West Midlands (county), B72, United Kingdom
   </result>
   <addressparts>
     <house>135</house>
     <road>Pilkington Avenue</road>
     <village>Wylde Green</village>
     <town>Sutton Coldfield</town>
     <city>City of Birmingham</city>
     <county>West Midlands (county)</county>
     <postcode>B72</postcode>
     <country>United Kingdom</country>
     <country_code>gb</country_code>
   </addressparts>   
 </reversegeocode>
```

You can then process the result as an xml document to find the city name node.

An alternative is to use [Google's Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).

Comment: Is There a way to retrieve the maxspeed using the reversegeocode?

Comment: Nominatim reverse-geocoding docs at https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/api/Reverse/

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [nominatim reverse geocoding API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) for this.

Here's an example of how you could get the city name (some code has been omitted for brevity):

```
final String requestString = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=" +
            Double.toString(lat) + "&lon=" + Double.toString(lon) + "&zoom=18&addressdetails=1";        

RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(requestString));
try {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                String city = "";
                try {
                    JSONValue json = JSONParser.parseStrict(response);
                    JSONObject address = json.isObject().get("address").isObject();
                    final String quotes = "^\"|\"$";

                    if (address.get("city") != null) {
                        city = address.get("city").toString().replaceAll(quotes, "");
                    } else if (address.get("village") != null) {
                        city = address.get("village").toString().replaceAll(quotes, "");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }            
            }
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```